# Database or Spreadsheet for global zip codes

Tags: database, powerbi, geolocation, geo

I found https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/geonames-postal-code%40public/export/?flg=en-us

to be a good source of zip-codes and country matches.

Is there a data source or an api which would provide for all.
I am interested in US and Global dataset.
I am going to use it for a PowerBI dashboard - I am aware of the internal tools available within PowerBI.

- ZIPCODE
- CITY
- STATE
- COUNTRY
- LAT
- LONG

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called IP2Location. they provide:

- [Free version](https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone)
- And also paid version